# how to optimize a linq query c# complex object?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am making a method that returns me the visitor's data, make this query with linq c #, which is the following,

```
public async Task<Models.Visitor> GetVisitorByEmail(string email)
{
    return (from v in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Visitor>().GetList()
            where v.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()
            select new Models.Visitor
            {
                VisitorId = v.VisitorId,
                FirstName = v.FirstName,
                SecondName = v.SecondName,
                FirstLastName = v.FirstLastName,
                SecondLastName = v.SecondLastName,
                Gender = (from g in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Gender>().GetList()
                          where g.GenderId == v.GenderId
                          select new Models.Gender
                          {
                              GenderId = g.GenderId,
                              GenderName = g.GenderName,
                          }).FirstOrDefault(),
                Email = v.Email,
                Telephone = v.Telephone,
                Family = (from vf in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<VisitorFamily>().GetList()
                          join f in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Family>().GetList()
                          on vf.FamilyId equals f.FamilyId
                          where vf.VisitorId == v.VisitorId
                          select new Models.Family
                          {
                              FamilyId = f.FamilyId,
                              FamilyName = f.FamilyName,
                              PhotoPath = f.PhotoPath
                          }).ToList(),
                Territory = (from vt in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<VisitorTerritory>().GetList()
                             join t in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Territory>().GetList()
                             on vt.TerritoryId equals t.TerritoryId
                             where vt.VisitorId == v.VisitorId
                             select new Models.Territory
                             {
                                 TerritoryId = t.TerritoryId,
                                 TerritoryName = t.TerritoryName,
                                 Axis = (from a in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Axis>().GetList()
                                         where a.AxisId == t.AxisId
                                         select new Models.Axis
                                         {
                                             AxisId = a.AxisId,
                                             AxisName = a.AxisName,
                                         }).FirstOrDefault(),
                             }).ToList(),
                IsActive = v.IsActive,
                PhotoPath = v.PhotoPath,
                UserTypeId = v.UserTypeId,
                UserId = v.UserId,
                CreateBy = v.CreateBy,
                CreationDate = v.CreationDate,
                ModifiedBy = v.ModifiedBy,
                ModifiedDate = v.ModifiedDate,
            }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I would like to know if I have 20 visitors for example, if the api that I am developing will give me good response times or is there another more optimal way to do it, since I am new to creating complex objects with linq c #, I am using ASP.NET CORE 3.1 and Core Entity Framework,

I would appreciate the help to optimize this query you made.

I am attentive to your suggestions

Comment: Most important: keep your statements `IQueryable<...>` as long as possible. Only add `ToList()` as last of your chain of LINQ statements. What does `GetList()` do?

Comment: This query will create Cartesian explosion `visitor * family * territory`. If it is ok, don't touch this query, otherwise you have to separate this query manually to three queries and combine result on the client side,

Comment: If it is possible, include in question generated SQL.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv No cartesian product because all queries are restricted by an id from the root entity.

Comment: `Visitor` should have navigation properties like `Gender`, `VisitorFamilies`, `VisitorTerritories` and these, in turn, their own navigation properties. It's an error to think that `Repository<Visitor>` should *only* return `Visitor` entities.

Comment: @GertArnold, so it is still cartesian explosion of records "restricted by an id from the root entity".

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv In that case, yes, at most `family * territory` per visitor, but EF is aware of that and will translate it into union queries.

Comment: @GertArnold, never heard that EF Core can translate Eager Loading into Union queries. Can you point me in documentation or other link?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm not aware of any docs on that, but I see it happen. Although EF core seems to be different. If so, I think that's a poor implementation because people can also have multiple `Include`s which shouldn't blow up with only two or three of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of style in which you must attach all nested entities:

```
public Task<IQueryable<Models.Gender>> GetGenderById(int id)
{
    return _unitOfWorkModel.Repository.Get<Gender>(x => x.GenderId = id).
}
```

In this example you're passing query on SQL server and return result in one record by `ToList()` (in `GetVisitorByEmail()` method).

`Get()` method must be in your base repository by default and all yours repos must inherit it with passing it's entity type to :

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly ApplicationDbContext DbContext;
        protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSetEntity;
        private readonly ILogger<BaseRepository<T>> _logger;

        protected BaseRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
            DbSetEntity = DbContext.Set<T>();

            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BaseRepository<T>>();
        }

        ...

        public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }
```

And use this method:

```
return (from v in _unitOfWorkModel.Repository<Visitor>
            where v.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()
            select new Models.Visitor
            {
                VisitorId = v.VisitorId,
                FirstName = v.FirstName,
                SecondName = v.SecondName,
                FirstLastName = v.FirstLastName,
                SecondLastName = v.SecondLastName,
                Gender = GetGenderById(v.GenderId).ToList(),
                Email = v.Email
...
```